# File backed UIImageView vs. NSURL Cache Control Policies

Tags: iphone, ipad, uikit, uiimageview, nsurlrequest

I am working on an image heavy iPad app. We implemented our own table view-esque control which reuses UIImageViews as a user scrolls the screen. To reduce network calls and make it perform better, I implemented a file backed UIImageView that writes the loaded images to the NSTemporaryDirectory and checks that before making a call to get a new image.

I should have looked at this before but I was later pointed to the different NSURLRequest Cache Policies.

My question is, is there any reason my custom file cache could perform better than the default cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather the iOS cache is memory only, so your homebrew cache will work better across app starts.